# AbstractUser object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-4.0

Below is my `model.py`

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
```

I override the default user model by providing a value for the AUTH_USER_MODEL
`setting.py`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'home.CustomUser'
```

But When I run server, I got `AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'model'`

What's problem in my code??

My `django version = 4.0`

full error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hello world\Desktop\python\django\django3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hello world\Desktop\python\django\django3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Hello world\Desktop\python\django\django3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Hello world\Desktop\python\django\django3\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Hello world\Desktop\python\django\django3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\checks.py", line 54, in check_admin_app
    errors.extend(site.check(app_configs))
  File "C:\Users\Hello world\Desktop\python\django\django3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 95, in check
    if modeladmin.model._meta.app_config in app_configs:
AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'model'
```

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback to your question?

Comment: I add full error!

Comment: Seems to be an issue with your admin configuration, can you show the admin.py where you register `CustomUser`?

Comment: Oh!! Thank you for help. I got it and fix it. I think I refer old syntax in `admin.py`.
How do you know admin.py has issue?

Comment: The error occurred in `check_admin_app` and the error was related to your model